# Why is RVIZ telling me that there is "No transfrom from [velodyne] to [base_link]" even though I have such a joint defined in my URDF?

Tags: ros

RVIZ is telling me that there is "No transfrom from [velodyne] to [base_link]".  I have a joint between these two objects defined in my  URDF file:

```
<robot name="jackal">
  <material name="orange">
    <color rgba="1.0 0.5 0.2 1" />
  </material>
  <material name="gray">
    <color rgba="0.2 0.2 0.2 1" />
  </material>


  <link name="velodyne">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.07" radius="0.05" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="gray" />
    </visual>
  </link>

  
  <link name="base_link" />



  <joint name="velodyne_to_base" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="velodyne" />
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
  </joint>

  
</robot>
```

Why am I getting this error even though I am defining such a joint?

Comment: Looks like you are not loading / publishing the transformations defined in the file. Could you check this?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg I do this by referencing the URDF in the Launch file, right?  I think I am doing this: 

<launch>
...
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />

    <param name="robot_description"
    textfile="$(find cartographer_ros)/urdf/jackal_vlp16_kvhIMU6.urdf" />
...
</launch>

Comment: @MichaelKossin Did this resolve your issue or are you still getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by inconsistencies between the "frame_id" property of the Velodyne launch file and the names used in the URDF file.  The link name in the urdf file must match the frame ID of the corresponding sensor.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to launch a [**`robot_state_publisher` node**](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) that publishes the `tf` transforms between your different links in any case - even if your links are connected with fixed joints only. Therefore either add

```
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"/>
```

to your **launch file** or open another terminal, source the current workspace and run the corresponding node

```
rosrun robot_state_publisher robot_state_publisher
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, once I launched this Robot State Publisher node this error stops happening.